# How do I remove /blog/ slug in URL in a WordPress custom type post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed custom type post in wordpress and it's working well. But when you try to post an article its displays /blog/ slug URL example `https://example.net/blog/best-construction-company`. And when I try to remove taxonomy in my code its removes slug but its display page is not found. Also when I try to false rewrite the rule it still displays/blog/ slug. Now, how do I remove /blog/ slug on my custom blog type? i.e `https://example.net/best-construction-company`

```
<?php
function equipments_blog_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Blog Post', 'blog posts and articles' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Blog', 'blog posts and articles' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Blog Post' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Blog Post' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Blog Post' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Blog Post' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Blog Posts' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Blog Post' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Blog Posts' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No blog posts found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No blog posts found in the Trash' ), 
        'menu_name'          => 'Blog Post'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Blog posts and articles',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'taxonomies')
    );

    register_post_type( 'blog', $args ); 
}
  
add_action( 'init', 'equipments_blog_post_type' );

function equipments_create_custom_taxonomies(){
    register_taxonomy('blog', 'posttypename', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Blog'));
    
    /* IMPORTANT: This is bad! Don't do this! Read the important update at the top of the page, and update 2 below for details */
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );/* Please read "Update 2" before adding this line */
}

add_action('init', 'equipments_create_custom_taxonomies' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do this, but a common issue with rewrites is not flushing the rewrite rules. Have you tried going into Settings -> Permalinks and click save to refresh the rewrite rules?

I still doubt this approach will work though -- I think you'll have to hotwire WordPress under the hood to allow your custom post types to behave like pages and posts.

See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, is it a Multi site or single? On the first scenario go to the main sites configuration e select the domain you want to change the slug, after procede to settings and permanent links and remove the slug blog and add anything like /%posname/
[See more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls)

Comment: Please avoid duplicating answers. You've answered pretty much the same thing and linked to the exacte same post than a previous answer.